# Access a specific column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and I would like to fetch a column in the form of a numeric array, if possible.

This is my code, but I am only able to get the first item.

```
<?php

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'starCreator', 'starCreatorPass','starsystem') or die ('starCreator: ... I couldn.t connect to the database, something is wrong with the authentication'.'<br />');

if ($dbc) 
    {
        echo 'starCreator: ... connection to the database is established'.'<br/>';
    }

$query = "SELECT name FROM stars";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];

?>
```

This row[1] doesn't retrun the second item.

Comment: Are you sure the query returns more than 1 row??

Comment: If you mean the query itself? Then yes - I tried this command using the terminal.

Comment: Alright then you got some right answers below :)

Answer (score 6):

`mysqli_fetch_array` only gets 1 row. The index of the row represents the columns, not the different values. To get the other values, you need to call `mysqli_fetch_array` multiple times, preferably in a loop :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to fetch a complete array (column)? Or do I have to create an array in the PHP file and then populate it looping through the rows?

Comment: @АлексейНаумов, no, you need to do it manually like : `$results = array();` and adding the value `$results[] = $row[0];` in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through the results (rows)

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM stars";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){

    echo $row[columnName];
    echo $row[anotherColumnName];

}
```